# Is there anyway to use pointers and callbacks in Elmer

Tags: python

I've been using Elmer to build wrap some python code in a DLL (see http://elmer.sourceforge.net/ for details on elmer).

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to construct the .elm file so that I can use pointer arguments or setup callback functions within elmer.

Inside the .elm file, instead retrieving a value like this:

```
double  get(int id)
```

I might want to do something like:

```
void  get(int id, double* val)
```

or set a callback

```
void registerCallback(int id, void (*MyCb)(double value) )
```

Just to clarify, this is within the .elm file that tells elmer how to wrap the python functions in the c-code for the dll, not within the c or python source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching through the elmer source code, I figured out how to do callbacks.  It doesn't appear there is any way to pass pointers (other than char *'s that are used for string types).

In the .elm file, first you need to define the callback function prototype, prefaced by the **callback** keyword.  Then you use the name of that callback as an argument to your function prototype within the .elm

```
#snipped from mytest.elm

#define callbacks types
callback int MyCb(int arg1, int arg2)

#function prototypes
int  register_callback(string someOtherArgs,  callback MyCb)
```

The python code will receive the callback function as any other argument, and it free to call it as if it were a native python function with the declared arguments.  You would have to craft your own looping mechanism in your python code if you wanted the callback continuously called (like most event handlers). One option is to loop until the callback returns zero; for example:

```
#snipped from mytest.py

def register_callback(someOtherArg, callbackFunc):
    cbArg1, cbArg2 = (1,2) #just some dummy values
    while(callbackFunc(cbArg1, cbArg2) == TRUE):
        print("I'm calling the callback...")
        time.sleep(.1)
```

To use this, you would have in your c/c++ code:

```
//snipped from mytest.c

//define the callback function.
//based on example python code, this would be called continuously until it
//returns 0
int MyAwesomeCallbackFunction(int arg1, int arg2) {/*definition goes here*/ return 1};

//register the callback and start the python based loop that calls MyAwesomeCallbackFunction
register_ui_callback("LadaDeDa", &myAwesomeCallbackFunction);
```